# quorum istanbul byzantine fault tolerance (ibft) consensus nodes count for failover - recommended configuration

Tags: consensus, quorum, ibft

In Quorum, specifically for istanbul byzantine fault tolerance (ibft) consensus algorithm, what is the ideal node count for failover? i.e., recommended configuration?

Nathan Aw (Singapore)

Answer (score 1):

The equation to solve that problem is the following:

The system can tolerate at most of F faulty nodes in a N validator nodes network, where N = 3F + 1

You can visit this link https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/650 in Consensus part to more information.

Answer (score 0):

recommended configuration?

no ideal or recommended config to offer.

just follow this:

IBFT mode of Quorum inherits from original PBFT and is 2f+1.
so if you assume you may have 1node as faulty one so 2*1+1 = 3 + 1f = 4nodes require to ensure ~2/3 of them reach consensus.